# Java KeepAlive check program not returning true for .checkError

Tags: java, linux, sockets, serversocket, unix-socket

We have lowered the TCP KeepAlive time on our servers from the default 7200s to 500s.
I am trying to write a small java program to check the that server is in fact using these updated settings.
If I manually do a telnet to the host from the command line it times out as expected.
When I run this program the  if (out.checkError()) is supposed to return true but it does not.  What can be the issue?

```
public class keepAlive5 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
//        String serverName = args[0];
        //String serverName = args[0];
//        int portNum = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
       // tstSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
        int portNum = 5500;
        int timeToWait = 600;
        String serverName = “host1”;
        try {
            Socket tstSocket = new Socket(serverName, portNum);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(tstSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            System.out.println("connected, now wait 10 minutes...");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(timeToWait);
        System.out.println("Will now check the connection..");
                out.write("try writing something");
        out.flush();
                if (!out.checkError()){
                    System.out.println("Socket closed by remote host");
                }
       } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Exception
        System.out.println("Unknown host..");
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write enough data so that the socket send buffer is filled, so that the write blocks, so that there is some possibilty of an error being detected and transmitted back to the application. Otherwise the writing process is asynchronous to the application, which will have closed the socket before the error is detected.

I would not use a `PrintWriter` for this task.

Comment: How much data would be enough?  If not PrintWriter what would you suggest?